# Circle images not working in codeflower d3.js

Tags: svg

I've tried very best to resolve issue of images not loading in circle. It shows transparent nodes. Kindly help.

json sample

```
 {"name":"root","icon":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/672863761674338304/V8Y88vu5.jpg","size":250,"value":44,"children":[{"id":"id0","icon":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/672863761674338304/V8Y88vu5.jpg","name":"@iHeartRadio","size":150,"value":48,"children":[{"id":"id1","icon":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/672863761674338304/V8Y88vu5.jpg","name":"@IamDiamondEyes","size":140,"value":44},{"id":"id6","icon":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/672863761674338304/V8Y88vu5.jpg","name":"@clearhair","size":90,"value":25}]},{"id":"id2","icon":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/672863761674338304/V8Y88vu5.jpg","name":"@Macys","size":130,"value":43},{"id":"id3","icon":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/672863761674338304/V8Y88vu5.jpg","name":"@natekristanto","size":120,"value":42},{"id":"id4","icon":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/672863761674338304/V8Y88vu5.jpg","name":"@CVGUpdates","size":110,"value":32},{"id":"id5","icon":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/672863761674338304/V8Y88vu5.jpg","name":"@w0nderfvl","size":100,"value":27},{"id":"id7","icon":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/672863761674338304/V8Y88vu5.jpg","name":"@BPlizak","size":180,"value":24},{"id":"id8","icon":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/672863761674338304/V8Y88vu5.jpg","name":"@courtneyerhard4","size":170,"value":24},{"id":"id9","icon":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/672863761674338304/V8Y88vu5.jpg","name":"@BriaKelly","size":160,"value":19},{"id":"id10","icon":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/672863761674338304/V8Y88vu5.jpg","name":"@bulbaqsauce","size":150,"value":19},{"id":"id11","icon":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/672863761674338304/V8Y88vu5.jpg","name":"@kubbyop","size":140,"value":19},{"id":"id12","icon":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/672863761674338304/V8Y88vu5.jpg","name":"@Lemonade229","size":130,"value":18}]}
```

Codeflower code: https://pastebin.com/VFS6DZie

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Solution was upgrading to d3.3